# Aptana Studio3 debugger not working

Tags: debugging, aptana

I am doing my 2D game project in Aptana Studio3. But when i click the debug button it goes to Aptana's home page. Also it shows the following error.

Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again.
Accept timed out

What is the problem .?
Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox,The problem may be with the Firebug installation;check the version .For some reason the version should not be the latest.It is better to allow Aptana studio to do the download of Fb and Aptana extension for FF.I had the same problem but was solved after doing as mentioned.